# Перенаправление потока вывода в "IDA Pro"

Tags: потоки-данных, дизассемблирование, ida-pro

Друзья, вопрос в следующем: 
**Как мне получить все, что принтует запущеная из командной строки программа?**

я запускаю программу IDA Pro через командную строку, скармливая ей файл **`.bin`** и файл скрипта **`.py`** (который и разберет указанный выше `.bin`). Команда выглядит так:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("idaq64 -A -S\"%s\parse_bin.py\" \"%s\"" % (_path_to_py, _path_to_bin), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
```

по задумке, когда я вызываю:

```
print p.communicate()
```

я должен получить весь вывод, который принтует программа всместе со скриптом. Однако я получаю список из 2х пустых элементов:

`'',''`

Comment: Если напрямую запустить из консоли, что-то в нее пишет?

Comment: Дело говорите. Не выводит нифига) Понял куда копать!